# BulkCopy not copying any data to database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to copy all the data from my datatable into my database.
I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Database File as my database.

Here's the code I'm using,

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1 = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Copy();
        SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection,
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers,
                transaction))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                "dbo.StudentInfIns";

            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt1);
                transaction.Commit();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea as to why it won't go through?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If so: *what* error?? If not: can you please show us your **connection string** used for this project?

Comment: Not getting any errors whatsoever. The code goes through. 
Here's my connection string:

String connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= |DataDirectory|MainDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

I've been using the same connection string throughout my program with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `AttachDbFileName=` approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `transaction.Commit();` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MainDB`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MainDB;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: I'd like to take this route but I don't want to over-complicate things by overhauling my entire DB setup right when I'm nearly done with my assignment. For something as simple as a local demonstration for a class assignment I just don't see the need. I'll definitely keep this in mind for future reference though.

Comment: Never mind, I went through with it and it was a lot easier than I thought it would be. Thank you!

Comment: @K.Saudi: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.